# How to use git command in AWS CodeDeploy command shell

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

When I actually go into EC2 and use the git command, it works fine, but when I use the CodeDeploy sh file, I get an error.
Here is the content.

```
LifecycleEvent - BeforeInstall
Script - . /hooks/codedeploy/deploy.sh
[stderr]Permission denied (publickey).
[stderr]fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Furthermore, I have Docker running in EC2, but when I try to enter the container by typing the command docker-compose exec app bash, it says that the container is not running.

```
[stderr]service "app" is not running container #1
```

The content of the sh file is as follows.

```
install.sh
#! /bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/
sh deploy.sh
```

This is the sh file in EC2.

```
/home/ec2-user/deploy.sh
#! /bin/bash
set -e
git pull origin develop
cd /home/ec2-user/myapp
docker-compose exec app bash -c "php artisan migrate && composer install"
```

Comment: When you run the git command manually, do you have to accept a new fingerprint?

Comment: No need to accept new fingerprints when manually executing git commands